# using jquery to increment values without refreshing on click

Tags: php, jquery, text, jquery-selectors, increment

I'm having problems with incremental values without refreshing the page using jquery.

I have html code that does this.

```
<li class=''>
<img src="../icons/fav_c.png" width='12' style='vertical-align:middle;'/>
&nbsp;&nbsp;
<div style='float:right;padding-top:2px;width:5px'>
<span class='selector'>
<?php echo $value; ?>
</span>
</div>
</li>
```

I have a code that does in jquery.

```
val value = $('span.selector').text();
$('span.selector').text(value++);
```

This is not affecting my value that is being echo'd out?
Can anyone see what the problem is? Does .text() not work?

Thanks!

Comment: Put **var** instead of **val**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok:

```
var value = $('span.selector').text();
value = parseInt(value, 10); // Use a radix!!!
$('span.selector').text(++value);
```

1. ) [parseInt with radix](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt)
   with out it '09' for example would be 0. Converts string to an integer
2. ) ++value - increment value before it's applied to .text(...). value++ would call text() first then increment.

Comment: Sorry, i was going to accept it but I had a time limit. and i just lost track of time. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
var value = $('span.selector').text();
value++;
$('span.selector').text(value);
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/alfonsoR/wYdZb/)

Answer (score 2):

`.text` expects a string

> Description: Get the combined text contents of each element in 
>       the set of matched elements, including their descendants.

[**http://api.jquery.com/text/**](http://api.jquery.com/text/)

try

```
var value = $('span.selector').text();
value = parseInt(value);
value++;
$('span.selector').text(value++);
```

**here is the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/XGGPw/**

Answer (score 1):

You can also try this

```
$("span.selector").text(function(i, v) {return parseInt(v, 10) + 1;});
```